# EditorFor/CheckBoxFor boolean adds data-val-required attribute to HTML without required attribute being added to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

My model class has a bool property without a Required attribute:

```
public class Test
{        
    public bool TestBool1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my razor view I am using EditorFor (Same thing happens with CheckBoxFor as well):

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TestBool1)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TestBool1)
</div>
```

This results in the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <label for="TestBool1">TestBool1</label>
    <input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The TestBool1 field is required." id="TestBool1" name="TestBool1" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input name="TestBool1" type="hidden" value="false">
</div>
```

Where is the data-val-required html attribute coming from?

Is there a way to stop it doing this without using `@Html.CheckBox("TestBool1", Model.TestBool1)` and setting the type to `bool?`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's coming from the fact that a `bool` must have a real value. I would be willing to bet if it were a `bool?` it wouldn't render that `data-val-required` attribute.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Changing it to `bool?` required a new EditorTemplate to using EditorFor (CheckBoxFor doesn't work at all) so that it is creates a checkbox instead of a drop down list.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

from this answer [Data annotations, why does boolean prop.IsRequired always equal true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957855/data-annotations-why-does-boolean-prop-isrequired-always-equal-true)

> DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
>
> Add this to your application_start. By default MVC adds [Required] to non-nullable value types (because you can't convert null into a bool, it must be a bool?)

you can prevent it happening, but as you will always send the bool (true or false) I usually leave it

Comment: The problem I am having is that without setting `AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes` to false I can't submit unchecked checkboxes as I get the message "This field is required."

Comment: @Richard Dalton that is wierd, I am actually working on exactly the same set up, noticed the validation (which is why i looked that other answer up) but I dont get validation errors if unchecked (I assumed it was as false is a value)

Comment: Ahh, turns out what was causing the validation to fail was some javascript that added a class of required to the elements that contained `data-val-required`. Changed that to use a different class and it's fine. Accepting you answer as it answers the question of how to remove the attributes. Thanks

Comment: @Richard Dalton glad it got sorted :)