# asp-for tag adds required field validation on checkbox in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, coreclr, tag-helpers, kendo-validator

I have asp.net core application and im trying to add simple checkbox without any validation. Checkbox is bound to boolean property on model. Below is the code

**Model**

```
public class MyModel
{  
    public bool IsEmployee { get; set; }
}
```

**cshtml**

```
 <form>
   <div>
       <label asp-for="IsEmployee">Is Employee</label>
       <input type="checkbox" asp-for="IsEmployee"/>             
   </div>
   <button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Save</button>
 </form>
 <script src="~/js/test.js"></script>
```

**javascript**

```
$(function () {
   var kendoValidator = $('form').kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
   $('#btnSave').click(function () {
    if (kendoValidator.validate()) {
        alert('true');
    }
    else {
        alert('false');
    }
   })
})
```

I am using `asp-for` tag helper on `input` element. Note that `IsEmployee` property DOES NOT have [Required] attribute.  But because of `asp-for` tag helper the rendered html has `data-val-required` and `data-val` attributes on  `input` element. It also adds one more **hiddden** `input` element with same name.
Below is rendered html.
(also note that i think it only happens when input type is checkbox. for textboxes its working fine)

```
 <form novalidate="novalidate" data-role="validator">
    <div>
        <label for="IsEmployee">Is Employee</label>
        <input name="IsEmployee" id="IsEmployee" type="checkbox" value="true" data-val-required="The IsEmployee field is required." data-val="true">             
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave" type="button">Save</button>
    <input name="IsEmployee" type="hidden" value="false">
</form>
```

I am using kendovalidator as well which adds `data-role="validator"` on form element.

**Issues**
There are 2 issues here
1> As soon as i click on check the box error message appears as `The IsEmployee field is required.`
2>kendoValidator.validate() method always returns false regardless of checkbox is selected or not.

Demo here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lax4u/z3oeux64/2/)

**Update 2**
We cannot bind nullable bool to checkbox. I am using asp.net core. I am not sure what the equivalent syntax in asp.net core for the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957855/data-annotations-why-does-boolean-prop-isrequired-always-equal-true) which is valid for classic asp.net

Comment: Hi @LP13, did you find a solution for this issue, I am facing the same thing at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Add data-validate="false" to the checkbox input.  The kendoValidator will ignore all inputs with that attribute set to false.

```
<input type="checkbox" asp-for="IsEmployee" data-validate="false" />
```

Comment: For me this worked (thanks!), but the attribute name needed to be `data-val` (instead of `data-validate`)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wan't the default generated html you have 2 choices.

1. Don't use it ! You are not forced to use the tag helpers, they are there for when you do need other html attributes generated. In this case just use < input name="IsEmployee" ...>
2. Change the way **asp-for** behaves for your checkbox. You can do this be either creating your own [IHtmlGenerater](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/4e1ec39a1f1d15a4ec74312809e3233bc106b77b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewFeatures/IHtmlGenerator.cs) or by extending the [DefaultHtmlGenerator](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/4e1ec39a1f1d15a4ec74312809e3233bc106b77b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewFeatures/DefaultHtmlGenerator.cs) and overriding GenerateCheckBox and possibly GenerateInput and then registering it with something like services.TryAddSingleton();

Hope this helpes you.